# How should I edit the query to improve performance while keeping the existing structure?

Tags: oracle

I want to improve the performance of the query as below. There is an index in the `isl_ref` and `isl_date` fields. But since I use the ">" operator and I use "+", index cannot be used. `(1/1440)` adds a minute to the `isl_date` field. How should I edit the query to improve performance while keeping the existing structure?

**SQL Query:**

```
   select name from persons
    where drm in ('G','B')
    and (isl_ref = 'QR' and sysdate > isl_date + (1 /1440) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phrase this as:

```
where drm in ('G', 'B') and
      isl_ref = 'QR' and
      isl_date < sysdate - (1 /1440)
```

You should be able to include `drm` in the index as well (as the  first or second column).  Oracle supports skip-scan index scanning.

Comment: @okoreni . . . Not naturally, but one could come up with something.  That would not change the performance, though.

Comment: I did a performance analysis, the your solution suggested did not affect performance, when I used "isl_date between sysdate  -1 and sysdate - (1/1440)" the performance improved, but do you think the logic is correct?

Comment: @okoreni - It is impossible to say if the logic is "correct", since you only showed us a query, you didn't tell us the business requirement. What is certain, though, is that your version is not equivalent to the original query - you added one more condition. Is that part of the requirement? (And if it is, why didn't the same condition exist in your original query?) The new version retrieves far fewer rows, so of course it should be faster.